# How often may a question be asked again?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, duplicates, closed-questions

I think there must be some kind of consideration to new ways of solving old problems.

Comment: Are you referring to a "follow-up question"? If so, see [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)

Answer (score 6):

The StackExchange model is that questions should be asked once (with duplicates closed as appropriate), but that answers can be added, edited or deleted over time. Thus for an older question where there is a change resulting in a new answer, the correct approach is to post a new answer (or if you also wrote the existing one perhaps to edit it). If you don't know the answer but believe a change is possible, adding a bounty will make the question 'active' and draws attention to it.

Comment: but doesn't this apply to questions that are about *exactly* the same problem?  if the question includes a new "wrinkle", it doesn't seem appropriate to modify the original question, at least unless the op is asked whether it's okay.  in such a case, i'd prefer to see a new question, with a reference to the old one, specifying just *why* it is different.

Comment: @barbara beeton Which is exactly what I was thinking. Frequently I've seen questions in Meta that are more or less "How do I ask a question about bla bla if there's a question about it and it's already closed?" I think, if a user justify it's question, knowing there has been some package actualization or something of the same nature, the question must be valid, especially if it's been like, say, 5 years since it was responded.

Comment: @EstebanMendoza Can you give some links?